# Azure Data Factory - REST API Call Pagination

Tags: json, pagination, azure-data-factory

I'm making a call for data in Data Factory and struggling to call the URL in the "next_page" item.

This is an example of what the first API call returns:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "title_one": "TTL-55924",
        "id": "CPT-TTL-64577_TTL-55924",
        "title_id": "TTL-64577"
    },
    {
        "title_one": "TTL-69015",
        "id": "CPT-TTL-79755_TTL-69015",
        "title_id": "TTL-79755"
    }
],
"next_page": "http://api.com/api/info?offset=5000&key=XXXxxxXXXxxx"
```

}

I'm not sure which options to use in the Pagination Rules of my Copy activity.

Currently I'm trying the option "AbsoluteURL" with the value `$['next_page']` but this just returns an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your API response contains the next page URL property, then the “**AbsoluteUrl**“ pagination rule is the correct option to load the **next page** in the Azure data factory.

The supported values for pagination rules are mentioned in this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support).

As mentioned in the example from the above document, Facebook Graph API returns the response as,

```
{
"data": [
    …
    …
],
"paging": {
    …
    …
    },
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=25&before=NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=25&after=MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE="
}
}
```

**Note**: Pagination value of a JSON path expression starts with “**$**”.

Your pagination in REST copy activity looks like this:

[image]

In your API, the pagination should look like

[image]

Comment: That's worked like a charm. The field next to "AbsoluteUrl" is a red herring. Thank you!

Comment: but do not forget to apply the correct "File pattern" in the sink. This is to be set to "Array of objects" otherwise your output will be a json file with per row a json "file" (aka an invalid overall json file)